# Enumerating paths from origin to a given point

Tags: combinatorics

As is [well known](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/938446/37092), there are $\binom{n+m}{n}$ paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n,m)$.

**Is there an easy way to *enumerate* the lexicographically ordered paths?**

IOW, how to map a given sequence of $n$ ones and $m$ zeros to a number from 1 to $\binom{n+m}{n}$ (and, v.v., such a number to such a sequence) **without** going through paths one-by-one (i.e., **in $O(n+m)$ time**).

**PS**. E.g., there are $6=\binom42$ paths from $(0,0)$ to $(2,2)$. If we denote a horizontal move as $0$ and a vertical one as $1$, here is the order of the paths:

1. $0011$
2. $0101$
3. $0110$
4. $1001$
5. $1010$
6. $1100$

Of course, lexicographical order is the same as the numeric order if we view the paths as binary representations of numbers.

**PPS**. Again, iteration over paths is **not** a solution here, but, for reference, here is how one might approach it in Python:

```
def sum_binary_digits(n):
    r = 0
    while n:
        r += n & 1
        n //= 2
    return r

def print_all_paths(n,m):
    path = 0
    tot = ncr(n+m,n)
    done = 0
    while done < tot:
        if sum_binary_digits(path) == m:
            print("{done:2d} {path:0{width}b} {path:{width}d}".format(
                done=done,path=path,width=n+m))
            done += 1
        path += 1
```

Comment: Could you elaborate, say by a small example, what is meant by a lexicographical order on the paths?

Comment: @coffeemath: done

Comment: So this is the same as if the binary number equivalents are listed in increasing order, at lest in this case. Does such binary increasing order always correspond with what you call lexicographical order?

Comment: @coffeemath: yes, of course.

Comment: In your example of (2,2) paths, are you wanting a rule that give the fourth entry on the list without listing the previous ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a fairly easy way to do it.  I'll just do an example, which will, I think make the procedure clear.  Let $m=n=4$ and suppose we want to find the index of the string $s=00101101.$  How many strings precede $s$?  Certainly any string that starts with three $0$'s does.  That leaves one $0$ and four $1$'s, so there are $\binom{5}{1}=5$ such strings.

Now we are left with strings that start with $001$.  There are the same number of such strings preceding $s$ as there are strings with two $0$'s and three $1$'s preceding $t=01101$.  Any such string starting with $00$ precedes $t$. There is only $1$ of those, and the problem is reduced to finding the number of strings with one $0$ and two $1$ preceding $101$.  There is $1$ such string starting with $0$, and the problem is reduced to finding the number of strings with no $0$'s and one $1$ preceding $1$. Clearly, there are none.

We have found that there are $5+1+1=7$ strings preceding $s$, so that $s$ is string number $8$.

**EDIT**

Here's a python script that implements this method.

```
from math import factorial

def choose(n,m):
    if m == 0:
        return 1
    return factorial(n)//(factorial(m)*factorial(n-m))

def predecessors(s):
    zeros = s.count('0')
    ones = s.count('1')
    if zeros == 0 or zeros == len(s):
        return 0
    n = s.index('1')
    if n == zeros:
        return 0
    return choose(len(s)-n-1,zeros-n-1)+ + predecessors(s[n+1:])

def test(m, n):
    from itertools import product
    P = list(''.join(p) for p in product('01', repeat = m+n) if p.count('1')==n)
    for idx, p in enumerate(P):
        assert predecessors(p) == idx
    print('Passed')
```

The `predecessors` function computes the number of predecessors of a given string $s$.  That is, it computes the number of binary strings with the same number of $0$'s and the same number of $1$'s as $s$, that precede $s$ in lexicographic order. To get the (one-based) index of $s$, you must add $1$.

The `test` function is just for testing that `predecessors` works.  For example, `test(5,3)` generates a sorted list of all strings with $5$ zeros and $3$ ones, and checks that  `predecessors` correctly computes the position of each string in the list.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. How to map back from the index (i.e., the return value of `predecessors` to the path?

Comment: Figure out where the first $1$ comes by comparing appropriate binomial coefficients to the index.  Then call recursively.  The functional parameters would have to include the number of zeros and ones, as well as the index.

Answer (score 1):

In the following PARI program, the `path` function will compute the k-th path from (0, 0) to (m, n) and the `inv` function will compute the index back:

```
path(m,n,k) = {
    my (p=vector(m+n));    \\ p will contain m 0's and n 1's
    for (s=1, #p,
        if (n==0, m--; p[s]=0,    \\ horizontal move
            m==0, n--; p[s]=1,    \\ vertical move
            my (c=binomial(m+n-1, n));
            if (k<=c,
                m--; p[s]=0,      \\ horizontal move
                n--; p[s]=1; k-=c \\ vertical move
            )
        )
    );
    p
}
inv(m,n,p) = {
    my (k=1);
    for (s=1, #p,
        if (p[s]==0,
                m--,
                n--;
                if (m,
                    k+=binomial(m+n,n+1)
                );
        );
    );
    k
}

m=2; n=4
for (k=1, binomial(m+n,n), print (k " " p=path(m,n,k) " " inv(m,n,p)))
```

The algorithm works as follows: to find the k-th path from (0,0) to (m,n):

- if (m,n)=(0,0), you're done (by necessity, k=1),
- else if m=0, move vertically (by necessity, k=1),
- else if n=0, move horizontally (by necessity, k=1),
- else if k <= binomial(m+n-1,n) then move horizontally and find the k-th path from (0,0) to (m-1,n),
- else move vertically and find the (k-binomial(m+n-1,n))-th path from (0,0) to (m, n-1).

Comment: I don't know PARI, but you appear to be using binomial coefficients in looping, which indicates that his is _precisely_ the solution I want to avoid by specifying **in (+) time**. At any rate, an explanation of the algorithm would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The algorithm works as follows: to find the k-th path from (0,0) to (m,n):
 - if (m,n)=(0,0), you're done,
 - else if m=0, move vertically,
 - else if n=0, move horizontally,
 - else if k <= binomial(m+n-1,n) then move horizontally and find the k-th path from (0,0) to (m-1,n),
 - else move vertically and find the (k-binomial(m+n-1,n))-th path from (0,0) to (m, n-1).
Provided that you have binomial(m+n,n) or a table of factorials, you can compute the other required binomials relatively fast.
I don't see how to avoid the use of binomial in this precise context.

Comment: Please incorporate the explanation into your answer, do not leave it in comments. Computing binomial coefficients is not a problem in itself.